# Android sqlite delete

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to develop an android application but I have a problem with SQLite.

in the application I can add or delete values ​​in the database, 
and in general  it works perfectly, but when I add "1.50" or "1.250" my method is unable to remove.

Method to remove a value :

```
    public int removeContenuWithTitre(String value){

    return bdd.delete(TABLE_CONTENU, COL_VALEUR + " = " +value, null);
}
```

Code that uses the method:

```
        buttonSup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View actuelView)   
        {
            // Si la zone de texte n'est pas vide :
            if(text3.getText().length() != 0)
            {


                ContenuBDD contenuBdd = new ContenuBDD(MainActivity.this);
                contenuBdd.open();

                String valText3 = text3.getText().toString();


                if(contenuBdd.recherche(valText3) == true)
                {

                    //not removed because the value is not the database

                }
                else 
                {
                    // deleting the value in the database :
                    contenuBdd.removeContenuWithTitre(valText3);


                }


                contenuBdd.close();
            }
            else 
            {

            }
        }
    });
```

code of the method "recherche" to see if a value is in the database :

```
public boolean recherche(String titre){

    Cursor c = bdd.query(TABLE_CONTENU, new String[] {COL_ID, COL_VALEUR}, COL_VALEUR + " LIKE \"" + titre +"\"", null, null, null, null);
    if(c.moveToFirst() == false)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
String[] args = {value};
bdd.delete(TABLE_CONTENU, COL_VALEUR + "=?", args);
```